# Returning a dataframe with all columns except for 'name'

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a more conventional or readable way of achieving the same result?

The below code works, but it feels clunky.

```
df[df.columns[~df.columns.isin(['name'])]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), here `:` means select all rows:

```
df.loc[:, ~df.columns.isin(['name'])]
```

Another idea is use [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) with `errors='ignore'` for avoid errors if not exist `name` column (same working like solution above):

```
df.drop('name', axis=1, errors='ignore')
```

Answer (score 1):

I am new to python. Can you not use:

```
df.loc[:, df.columns != 'name']
```